# Loop through list element and add text to the input value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basicaly I want to loop through and get the text of from the first ul  then append it to the input value on .second ul

```
<ul class="first">
    <li>
        <p>test one </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="second">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q3" value="Yes">
        <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q3" value="No" checked="">
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="first">
    <li>
        <p>text two </p>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q4" value="Yes">
        <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q4" value="No" checked="">
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to apply this way but its not working properly

```
$("ul.first li p").each(function () {
    $("ul.second li input").val($("ul.second li input").val() + "_" + $(this).text());
});
```

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
<input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q4" value="Yes_text two ">
<input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q4" value="No_text two " checked="">
```

Comment: where do you want to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$(".first").each(function () {
    var radio = $(this).next().find("input[type='radio']");
    var value=$(this).find("p").text();
    radio.each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val() + "_"+ value   );

    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/82/)

Answer (score 0):

As you can pass a function in the jquery's `.val(fn)` method to return the value, we can use that to get the desired output. whenever you use a function in it then you have to return the values with `return` keyword.

Use this:

```
$("input[type='radio']").val(function(){
    return this.value + '_' + $(this).closest('ul').prev('ul').find('p').text().trim();
});
```

```js
$("input[type='radio']").val(function() {
      return this.value + '_' +
      $(this).closest('ul').prev('ul').find('p').text().trim();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="first">
  <li>
    <p>test one</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="second">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q3" value="Yes">
    <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q3" value="No" checked="">
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="first">
  <li>
    <p>text tow</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q4" value="Yes">
    <input type="radio" name="wis_con_q10_q4" value="No" checked="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

<sub>*You have to inspect to see the values.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.first li p").each(function (index,val) {
    $("ul.second li input").eq(index).val($("ul.second li input").val() + "_" + $(this).text());
});
```

.each from Jquery send index and value as parameters, you can use it with .eq(nb) to get the nb element.